# Function that returns exact string matches from multiple columns based off a word list

Tags: vba, excel, string-matching

I was hoping to receive help editing this helpful piece of code:

```
Function ListSearchB(text As String, wordlist As String, Optional caseSensitive As Boolean = False)
Dim strMatches As String
Dim res As Variant
Dim arrWords() As String
arrWords = Split(wordlist)
On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear
For Each word In arrWords
    If caseSensitive = False Then
        res = InStr(LCase(text), LCase(word))
    Else
        res = InStr(text, word)
    End If
    If res > 0 Then
        strMatches = strMatches & word
    End If
Next word
If Len(strMatches) <> 0 Then
    strMatches = Right(strMatches, Len(strMatches))
End If
ListSearchB = strMatches
End Function
```

This code works excellent for what it does currently. First it selects the text string to compare, then selects the array of comma separated words its looking to find matches to. If any of the words in the text string match to a word in the array it will return that match.

What I'm looking to add to it is to be able to select the first cell with text, then a second cell with text, and then the array itself and return any and all matches from both selected cells that match.

I tried all day trying to get it to work but I've been getting errors each time.

example would look like:

A1: apples taste better than the oranges

B1: strawberries are the best berry

C1(array): apples, strawberries, blueberries, peaches, oranges

D1(output): apples oranges strawberries

Comment: Will your inputs always be 2 cells?

Comment: All you should need to do is concatenate (with a space separator) the strings you want to test.  e.g:  `=ListSearchB(CONCATENATE(A1," ",B1),C1)`

Answer (score 0):

Some functions to help you:

```
'To check if an element is within a specific Array, Object, Range, String, etc.
Public Function isInArray(ByVal itemSearched As Variant, ByVal aArray As Variant) As Boolean
Dim item As Variant

If VarType(aArray) >= vbArray Or VarType(aArray) = vbObject Or VarType(aArray) = vbDataObject Or TypeName(aArray) = "Range" Then
    For Each item In aArray
        If itemSearched = item Then
            isInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next item
    isInArray = False
ElseIf VarType(aArray) = vbString Then
    isInArray = InStr(1, aArray, itemSearched, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 'Comparing character by character
Else
    On Error Resume Next
    isInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(itemSearched, aArray, False)) 'Slow on large arrays
    Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
End If

End Function

'To check if a word is within a sentence-like string
Public Function isInStrArray(ByVal itemSearched As Variant, ByVal strSource As Variant) As Boolean
Dim strArr As Variant

isInStrArray = False
If VarType(itemSearched) = vbString And VarType(strSource) = vbString Then
    itemSearched = Trim(itemSearched): strSource = Trim(strSource)
    If Len(itemSearched) > 0 And Len(strSource) > 0 Then
        strArr = Split(strSource) 'Splitting at each space
        isInStrArray = isInArray(itemSearched, strArr)
        Erase strArr
    End If
End If

End Function
```